# Automapper Project().To Error A query body must end with a select

Tags: automapper

I'm trying to prevent that a query to an entity bring more columns than necessary. Should only bring those columns specified in the target model.
Below is my code built following some examples to achieve my goal but I get syntax error "A query body must end with a select clause or a group clause linq”
int the query line.

```
        var studentEventsModel = from c in DbContext.StudentEvent.Project().To<StudentEventViewModel>();
```

Please let me know what I’m doing wrong.

```
  public IEnumerable<StudentEventViewModel> GetStudentEventsListViewModel()
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<StudentEvent, StudentEventViewModel>();
        var studentEventsModel = from c in DbContext.StudentEvent.Project().To<StudentEventViewModel>();
        return studentEventsModel;
    }
```

Comment: Add " select c" to the end of your query?

Answer (score 0):

As @hometoast mentioned you may add select at the end of your query like this:

```cs
var studentEventsModel = 
 from c in DbContext.StudentEvent.Project().To<StudentEventViewModel>() select c;
```

or alerternatively you may use the lambda expression like this:

```cs
var studentEventsModel = DbContext.StudentEvent.Project().To<StudentEventViewModel>();
```

And as to the question on why you are seeing that error, it is due to the fact that a query syntax must end with `select` or `group`, mentioned [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384065.aspx) in the documentation.

> A query expression must begin with a from clause and must end with a
>   select or group clause. Between the first from clause and the last
>   select or group clause, it can contain one or more of these optional
>   clauses: where, orderby, join, let and even additional from clauses.
>   You can also use the into keyword to enable the result of a join or
>   group clause to serve as the source for additional query clauses in
>   the same query expression.